# The order of a rational section is zero at all but finitely many points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, valuation-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Noetherian, regular and integral scheme with function field $K$. Moreover let $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Take a nonzero rational section $s\in \Gamma(L\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} K)$, then at each point $x\in X$ we can write $s_x=f_xe_x$ for $f_x\in K$ and $e_x\in L$. In other words we have chosen a local basis $\{e_x\}_{x\in X}$ for $L$.-

If $x$ is a point of codimension $1$ we have a discrete valuation on $K$ associated to $x$, and we denote it simply by $v_x$. Now we can put:

$$\operatorname{ord}_x(s):=v_x(f_x)$$

It is easy to show that $\operatorname{ord}_x(s)$ doesn't depend on the local basis chosen,  but

> I don't understand why $\operatorname{ord}_x(s)=0$ for all but
>   finitely many points of codimension $1$.

Can you please explain  it?

---

**Edit:** Equivalently a rational section $s$ can be seen as a nonzero element of $L_{\eta}$ where $\eta$ is the generic point of $X$. Clearly for any $x\neq \eta$ we have $L_\eta=L_x\otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}} K$. The problem is still there. I don't understand why the order is zero almost everywhere.

Comment: Can you do this when $X$ is affine? If so, can you reduce this to the affine case?

Comment: I can do this only in the analytic setting, for example when $X$ is a compact  Riemann surface. In this case we use the property of poles of meromorphic functions. In the algebraic setting I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my hint should have made you think  what to do.

First, you can find an affine open set $U=\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ where $L|U\cong A$.Since there are only finitely many irreducible components in $X-U$, we can ignore these for your question and thus assume $X=\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ and $L\cong A$. Now, $s$ is a non-zero rational section of $L$ implies $s$ can be written as $a/b$, $a,b\in A$, both non-zero. There are only finitely many codimension one supports in $a=0$ and $b=0$ and it is clear that for any $x$ of codimension one other than these, $\nu_x(s)=0$.